# Java : In ConcurrentHashMap , why is having differnet output if i changes the key

Tags: java, collections, concurrenthashmap

**First iteration:-**

```
class ConcurrentHashMapBehaviour
{       
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("ONE", 1);
        map.put("TWO", 2);
        map.put("THREE", 3);
        map.put("FOUR", 4);
        Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) it.next();
            System.out.println(key+" : "+map.get(key));
            map.put("SEVEN", 7);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output is :**

```
ONE : 1
FOUR : 4
TWO : 2
THREE : 3
SEVEN : 7
```

**Second Iteration after changing the key**

```
class ConcurrentHashMapBehaviour
{       
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new 
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

        map.put("ONE", 1);
        map.put("TWO", 2);
        map.put("THREE", 3);
        map.put("FOUR", 4);
        Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) it.next();
            System.out.println(key+" : "+map.get(key));
            map.put("FIVE", 5);
        }           
    }
}
```

**Output is:**

```
ONE : 1
FOUR : 4
TWO : 2
THREE : 3
```

So my question is why first iteration include the SEVEN as output but not FIVE in second iteration?

Comment: Presumably, "FIVE" goes into a bucket that the iterator has already visited.  I don't understand why you find this odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javadoc (with my emphasis):

> Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table ***at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration***.

In other words, there are NO guarantees on the view available to the iterator.  It may or may not be aware of changes to the map after the `Iterator` is created.  The only guarantee is

> They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: That's the answer (y)

Answer (score 0):

When you type

```
Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    String key = it.next();
    System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));
    map.put("FIVE", 5);
}
```

You might put `("FIVE", 5)` to the map each time you print a value, but that doesn't add it to the running iterator. The iterator does not update. In fact, changing an iterating list or map without an iterator (for example with a for each-loop) would result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

---

When you do a second loop after your first and create a new iterator. It will also print out the new value:

```
Iterator<String> it2 = map.keySet().iterator();
while (it2.hasNext())
{
    String key = it2.next();
    System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));
}
```

Output:

```
FIVE : 5
ONE : 1
FOUR : 4
TWO : 2
THREE : 3
```